# Can't seem to access EC2 machines from Virgin Media connections?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, iis

This one's a weird one. I have a couple of clients with standard Windows Server instances running IIS. From anywhere else in the world, they and anyone else can access the webpages that those machines serve through a browser, as well as RDP if they are authorised. However, from a Virgin Media connection, they can't. Attempting to access their webpages through a URL results in a generic "Page not found" browser message, and attempting to access their pages through the IP address results in a "Server was reset" message. Furthermore, RDP times out.

Any reason why this could be? It's only Virgin Media so far.

Comment: AWS runs a significant fraction of the internet. If there was a general block of AWS by VM or vice versa it would be fairly obvious. Try different protocols, check all your firewalls, talk to tech support for both providers. Report back once you've done that, edit your question with all the information you learn - I expect it'll take a few days to a few weeks.

Comment: @Tim I posted a question on the AWS forum too, but we're a super small outfit and we don't have a support plan for AWS yet - my clients are social enterprises so there's not a lot of money for IT. I did try and contact a network engie at VM, but it was through a sales guy at some random callcentre so I'm not hopeful. Thing is, it's not just one client. It's eight, all facing the same issue. All of them have machines with IPs from the 35.x.x.x block. I've never seen anything quite like it, and I was able to RDP into EC2 machines just last year on VM. No user-end network changes since then...

Comment: Then I guess a process of elimination will be required. Get some IPs from a different range - they're assigned randomly. Try different regions / AZ. See if you can isolate it. Once you have a bit more information AWS may see it in their forums and help address is.